# How do I add a sprite to a viewcontroller?

Tags: swift, xcode, sprite-kit

I have made my Viewcontroller to a SKview so I can add things.

```
let skview: SKView = {
    let view = SKView()
    view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    return view
}()

self.view.addSubview(skview)

skview.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor).isActive = true
skview.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
skview.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.rightAnchor).isActive = true
skview.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leftAnchor).isActive = true
```

`self.addchild(player)` doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't add a sprite to a view controller. You can't neither add a sprite to a `SKView`. You must first create a `SKScene` and present it:

```swift
let scene = SKScene(size: skview.bounds.size)
skview.presentScene(scene)
```

Then you can add sprites to the scene:

```swift
scene.addChild(player)
```